# iOS not able to pass all nodes from firebase to Tableview in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I've been trying to pass my Firebase Database data/value into my tableviewcell

It worked, but there's only one showed in my tableview while I have 5 menukeys in my database.

my code is like the following

```
 DataService.ds.REF_MENUS.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in


        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot]
        {
            print ("\(snapshot)")

            for snap in snapshot {
                print("SNAP: \(snap) ")


                if let menuDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, String> {

                    print ("SNAP\(menuDict)")

                   let key = snap.key
                   let menu = menuContnet(menuKey: key, menuData: menuDict)

                    self.menus.append(menu)
                    self.WeekMenu.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

I did some printing trying to debug.

at `print("SNAP: \(snap) ")` I got all 5 keys with their children from database

but at `print ("SNAP\(menuDict)")` there's only one key with it's children left

I think it's this line that causing issue

aren't menuDict suppose to be an Array with all keys and it's value?

my keys are just Strings, I tried to do `if let menuDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` but it won't really work

can some one please point out which part is causing the problem?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I change this

```
if let menuDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, String>
```

to

```
 if let menuDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

and print, I can get all keys and their children from database but it then crashes saying that i got this error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

**UPDATE**

[crashes like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvhuS.png)

it's killing me.... I've been trying to figure this out for 3 days :(

**UPDATE**

it looks like the values are found nil because i gave value a string of numbers in my database, as long as i give values number and letter mixed value it will work

BUT here comes an other little problem :

if i change values in Firebase database and run the app again, it catches the new value i change but it show the old value on my tableviewCell

i wonder how is that happening @_@

Comment: At which line exactly does it crashes? And give your current DB structure as text not as picture

Comment: `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` This is a *really* hard message to understand, I know, but it means you force-unwrapped an optional that is `nil`. So find the line where you are force-unwrapping an optional, and don't.

Comment: Hi, i update a screenshot

Comment: Okay, so in my firebase database i gave value with all numbers like "45645643" and it won't work. as long as i give value like "5436fgfh52435"
it just worked...

Comment: Hey Guys thanks for helping me out ! The problem is almost done, just a little problem to deal with, i updated the question and please kindly take a look!

Comment: problem fixed !! i accidentally linked wrong UIlabel to UItableviewcellcontroller..